# How can I add "paragraph breaks" to my html email?

Tags: c#, html, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to add paragraph breaks in the email messages I generate. I've tried both Environment.NewLine and adding multiple html paragraphs:

```
// Take 1, using Environment.NewLine:
htmlBody.Add(string.Format("<p>Hello {0}. You have been assigned the {1} on the " +
"<em>Apply Yourself to the Field Ministry</em> midweek meeting for the week beginning {2}.{3}{3}" +
"Your counsel point is {4}; if this is not a Bible reading, your HH is {5};{3}{3}" +
"You can find the material for your assignment in your Meeting Workbook.{3}{3}" + 
"Thank your for your paticipation!</p>",
    fullName, friendlyTalkType, weekOfTalk.ToLongDateString(), Environment.NewLine, counselPoint, HH, MWURL));

// Take 2, using p tags:
htmlBody.Add(string.Format("<div><p>Hello, {0}. You have been assigned the {1} on the " +
"<em>Apply Yourself to the Field Ministry</em> midweek meeting for the week beginning {2} (actual date is {3}).</p><p></p><p></p>" +
"<p>Your counsel point is {4}; if applicable, your HH is {5};</p><p></p><p></p>" +
"<p>You can find the material for your assignment in your Meeting Workbook or online here: {6}</p><p></p><p></p>" +
"Thank your for your participation!</p></div>",
    fullName, friendlyTalkType, weekOfTalk.ToLongDateString(),
    weekOfTalk.AddDays(DAYS_BETWEEN_MONDAY_AND_THURSDAY).ToLongDateString(),
    counselPoint, HH, MWURL));
```

In neither case is there vertical separation between the sections of text. What hoop do I need to vault myself through to accomplish this?

For context, here is the entire method:

```
public static void SendEmail(string fullName, string toEmail, string HH, int talkType, DateTime weekOfTalk, int counselPoint)
{
    const int DAYS_BETWEEN_MONDAY_AND_THURSDAY = 3;
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_EMAIL_NAME);
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(toEmail, fullName);
    string fromPassword = GMAIL_PASSWORD;
    string subject = $"{UPCOMING_AYttFM_ASSIGNMENT} ({weekOfTalk.ToLongDateString()})";
    string friendlyTalkType = GetTalkTypeAsStringForInt(talkType);
    string body;
    string MWURL = GetLinkForMeetingWorkbookForWeek(weekOfTalk);

    List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
        {
            "<html><body>"
        };
    htmlBody.Add(string.Format("<div><p>Hello, {0}. You have been assigned the {1} on the " +
     "<em>Apply Yourself to the Field Ministry</em> midweek meeting for the week beginning {2} (actual date is {3}).</p><p></p><p></p>" +
     "<p>Your counsel point is {4}; if applicable, your Householder is {5};</p><p></p><p></p>" +
     "<p>You can find the material for your assignment in your Meeting Workbook or online here: {6}</p><p></p><p></p>" +
     "Thank your for your participation!</p></div>",
        fullName, friendlyTalkType, weekOfTalk.ToLongDateString(),
        weekOfTalk.AddDays(DAYS_BETWEEN_MONDAY_AND_THURSDAY).ToLongDateString(),
        counselPoint, HH, MWURL));

    htmlBody.Add("</body></html>");
    body = string.Join("", htmlBody.ToArray());

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a simple `<BR>`?

Comment: If you mean </br>, I tried that, too (unsuccessfully, obviously).

Comment: Also in the second case you can try to use  `<p>&nbsp;</p>` instead of empty `<p></p>`

Comment: @valex: Really? I *do* want it to break...or is nbsp a misnomer?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: It's a non-breaking space symbol (a viewer can't shrink it). So if you use it inside of paragraph you get a non-empty paragraph and a viewer has to reserve a block space for it on the page. Finally you get a blank line between paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `</br>` tag in paragraph. like this

```
htmlBody.Add(string.Format("<p>Hello </br>. You have been assigned the </br> on the " +
"<em>Apply Yourself to the Field Ministry</em> midweek meeting for the week beginning </br>" +
"Your counsel point is </br>; if this is not a Bible reading, your HH is </br>}" +
"You can find the material for your assignment in your Meeting Workbook.</br>" + 
"Thank your for your paticipation!</p>",
```

Comment: Thanks, sourabh; Once I double the breaks, it works (and removed them from where placeholders belong).

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `<br>` in the Body-String.